# Connect to a remote socket.io server from Django server

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, express, socket.io

I am trying to build a real-time Django application.
Because of the way my hosting service works, I am unable to start a Websocket server in parallel of my Django server.

I managed to have user-to-user interactions by creating an **express** server on a separate NodeJS website with **socket.io**, and having clients on the Django server also connect to the remote socket.io server.

However, I'dlike to have my Django server directly send events to users. To do this, I would like to create a connection between the Django server and the NodeJS server. Something like that in python:

```
socket = io("http://socket.io.server")
socket.emit('eventForUsers')
```

Is there anyway for me to achieve this?

The only information I found seemed to require me to run a parallel server from my Django app, which I can't do because my host doesn't allow me to run long-term processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what is the most simple solution for you, and what are your requirements. (If you want realtime bidirectional messaging then I suggest to use the socket.io-client instead of the `POST` example)

---

## POST (GET,PUT,...)

You can (for example) use `POST` requests from your Django to Node

**Django:** `python` example (there are other ways to perform a POST to Node from Django)

```
reqParams = {"action":"doThis","data":"put the pizza in the oven"}    
import requests
requests.post('http://ip:port/route', params = reqParams)
```

**Node** example : Listens for post at `/route` (express) and prints the params of the Django request

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/route', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query); res.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Then you can use the data in `req.params` to perform action like broadcasting something to the `socket.io` clients (or a specific client)

This can also be done the other way around, performing requests to send data from Node to Django using `POST (GET,...)`

---

## `Socket.io-client` in Django

Another (easier) solution is to include the [`socket.io-client`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) in your Django webapp so it connects to your Node `socket.io` server as a client when the webapp is opened by browsers.

(using javascript in django)

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://ip:port');
  socket.on('connect', function(){alert("Hello World!");});
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
```

**More Resources :**
 1. [JavaScript (Django Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/javascript/) 
 2. [Including the static files in your template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Nice, the first solution seems pretty smart I will try it out and let you know. About the second solution: unless I missed something, this will only connect the user to socket.io, but not the django server itself right? I don't see how I can use this method to have a communication Django -> client

Comment: @RyanPergent I dont know your exact scenario, thats why I suggest both, so you can think which solution suits you best (if you want webapp users to connect like clients **socket.io** / else if you want the webapp itself as a 'client' then use **request**).

Comment: The first method is working great, the only thing is that's it's `req.query` and not `req.params` :). Thanks!